# httpHeaders and caching for mobile detect

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, http-headers

I have a client site that uses httpHeaders to do mobile detection. It works really well, however, whenever I try to use dynamic nginx caching, file-based caching and or memcached caching, desktop browsers sometimes show mobile content.

It is intermittent and hard to reproduce. I have tried removing the mobile detect script (php) from the cache, but that doesn't seem to work.

The script fires on most of the pages on our site. Any thoughts on how to have caching on our site without interfering with the httpHeaders script we are using, if dynamic (nginx), file-based caching, or mem-cached caching could be causing the problem, is appreciated.

This is a wordpress site. Here is more info on the types of caching available to us:

Dynamic caching: Store your content in the server's memory for a faster access with full-page caching solution powered by NGINX. Having Dynamic Cache is essential for speeding up your website.

File Based Caching: With file-based caching enabled we will create static HTML versions of your website which will be served to future visitors. The files are stored in the browser memory.

Memcached: Powerful object caching for your site. Memcached stores frequently executed queries to your databases and then reuses them for better performance.

Comment: _"site that uses httpHeaders"_ - which is what, exactly? (Finding a ton of different stuff under that name.) _"It is intermittent and hard to reproduce."_ - it will probably simply depend on which type of client triggered the last cache update? (Meaning, you could have the same problem the other way around.) If this thing is checking the content of specific HTTP request headers, then your caching probably needs to be set up with a `Vary` response header.

Comment: Thank you and sorry that wasn't very clear. I am using this script: https://github.com/dmhendricks/detect-remote-device/blob/master/vendor/mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib/Mobile_Detect.php and I believe it uses the user agent. Caching causes a false mobile positive result on desktop intermittently. My best guess is that the http header is being cached, would dynamic nginx caching, file-based caching and or memcached caching be more likely to cause that?

Comment: That script seems to look for a lot more different possible headers, than just the UA - https://github.com/dmhendricks/detect-remote-device/blob/master/vendor/mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib/Mobile_Detect.php#L130 _"My best guess is that the http header is being cached"_ - no, the issue is that your system only keeps _one_ cached version (of the documents, not the headers), whereas should keep several different ones.

Comment: Ah, so the cache is serving up static HTML not a PHP page. That would be a problem. I want to cache the images, JS, and CSS, but have the page serve up via PHP.

If I understand it properly memcache should be ok if it focuses on queries to the database- File based caching won't work in our case. I will ask my host if their nginx solution caches static HTML, or if there is a way for them to prevent that and cache other the files.

Does CDN serve up static HTML do you know?